# simulate login on webpage with javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, react-native, web

How can I simulate a login on a webpage with react native? If someone has a solution with javascript I will accept it, too.

I just want to get the Informations from a Website in my App.
I dont want to use a Webview. I just need the HTML code and there I will look which information I will need.

[image]

The 302 redirect request has no answer, but in the params I see the password and the username from the login form and on the cookies I have this:*(I have cut the image to half because of security reasons)*.

[image]

This is the header:
[image]

In the second request is a redirect request, too. There are some Cookie Informations, too.

And the third request (Get request) is successfull. The header looks like this:
[image]

And the response is the HTML Code. The HTML code is what I want.

My first idea was to copy the curl request and transform it to javascript.
https://curl.trillworks.com/
  But I dont know how to handle with cookies... Somebody can help me?
I thought to use something like request.js or axios

Comment: There's really not much we can work with here. The answer is a solid "Maybe" and it's going to take a lot of experimenting on your part to get something to work. If you have a minimal self-contained example we can experiment with and get functional then this is on-topic, otherwise it's probably not.

Comment: okay... i dont understand why they use the redirections? Is it for security reasons?

Comment: Login systems do that for many reasons, security being one. Another is they need to track logins, set cookies on particular domains, or simply because of way the application is constructed. Google, for example, does upwards of ten redirects when logging in through some pages.

Comment: maybe somebody has experience with this kind of problem? I only just need some hints and tips...

Comment: I get what you're saying, but advice-type questions are off-topic here since the strict question-answer format isn't really able to accommodate them. You could try other sites like [Quora](https://www.quora.com).

Comment: maybe i can use a webview in background to simulate the login?